# Ghost blog Label Navigation with multiple domains

Tags: dns, navigation, blogs, ghost

I'm using a selfhosted ghost blog and wanted to integrate the navigation feature with ghost blog. In the AdminPanel navigation tab I can assign labels and point them to an url. Worked fine for as long as I had one domain.

Now I'm using two domains which point to the same blog. I want the visitor to stay in the namespace of the domain he visited.

Expample:

domain1 --> blog home

domain2 --> blog home

In the Navigation setting I can only set a label and point it to an url.
this works fine with domain 1 because I set home to point to domain1.

But if a user is visiting my blog from domain2 and he clicks on home he gets redirected to the home of my blog on domain1 and the address in the browser changes.

How can I differentiate the two domains in ghost blog since the navigation seems only be able to point to one specific url?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same thing on the Ghost Forum, here was the answer I received:

[Ghost Blog Forum](https://forum.ghost.org/t/define-multiple-urls-in-ghost-config/7852)

It's not something that is currently supported and due to the CORS checking done by Ghost, it won't serve it to you even if your reverse proxy is set for multiple domains.